# Como passar uma QueryString usando o RegisterStartupScript no asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Eu tenho este código no meu code behind:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", ""), "window.setTimeout(\" $('#" + calendar.ID + "').fullCalendar({header: {left: 'prev,next today',center: 'title',right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'},aspectRatio: 2.2,editable: true,events: " + sJSON + ", eventClick: function(event) { OpenModal('Novo Compromisso','100%','500px','/agenda/form.aspx?compromissoid=event.id');}});\",100);", true);
```

Ele pega alguns dados e carrega a propriendade do full calendar. Em eventClick eu quero acessar o valor de event.id para abrir uma janela modal e editar o evento. Mas o valor da querystring está sendo atribuído como 'event.id' literalmente.

Eu chequei o valor de event.id para ver se havia algo ali. O valor existe porque ele aparece na função alert() como visto abaixo:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", ""), "window.setTimeout(\" $('#" + calendar.ID + "').fullCalendar({header: {left: 'prev,next today',center: 'title',right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'},aspectRatio: 2.2,editable: true,events: " + sJSON + ", eventClick: function(event) { alert(event.id); OpenModal('Novo Compromisso','100%','500px','/agenda/form.aspx?compromissoid=event.id');}});\",100);", true);
```

Então, como eu posso usar o valor de event.id como valor para a querystring?

Answer (score 1):

Se mais alguém estiver sofrendo com isso está aqui a resposta que me deram no SO em inglês.

Na chamada OpenModal, mude a url '/agenda/form.aspx?compromissoid=event.id' para: '/agenda/form.aspx?compromissoid=' + event.id

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", ""), "window.setTimeout(\" $('#" + calendar.ID + "').fullCalendar({header: {left: 'prev,next today',center: 'title',right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'},aspectRatio: 2.2,editable: true,events: " + sJSON + ", eventClick: function(event) { alert(event.id); OpenModal('Novo Compromisso','100%','500px','/agenda/form.aspx?compromissoid=' + event.id);}});\",100);", true);
```

Tradução livre deste link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185168/how-to-pass-a-querystring-using-registerstartupscript/25185301#25185301

Erro de principiante meu...